# How to create a labeled categorical heatmap in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, histograms

Given the data: `{{1.4, 0}, {0, 1.0}}` I can create a heatmap using

```
DensityHistogram[{{1.4, 0}, {0, 1.0}}, {1}]
```

[image]

However, the tick marks are not informative. I need for the heatmap to show actual labels for each column and row. I need something like:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I have tried adjusting the bin size but that still leaves the numbers and tick marks; it just changes their spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
d = {{1.4, 0}, {0, 1.0}};
ticks = Transpose[{{1, 2}, {"Seq1", "Seq2"}}];
MatrixPlot[d, FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks, ticks, ticks}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great.  Thank you!  This will work great.